# SQL Server Express equivalent for EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sql-server-express

As per https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-query-getting-started-vertical/, it is now possible for one database in Azure SQL to query other Azure SQL databases. For my use case, I plan to have one database serving reference data for other databases, which fits nicely to Topology 1 (vertical sharding).

This is great for a deployed environment, but for local development I typically develop using SQL Server Express. As of SQL Server 2012 Express, the `CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE` is not a valid syntax.

Is it possible to also reap the benefit of external data source for local development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After weighing the feature sets, I decided to differentiate the setup of my local database and Azure SQL.

- When local SQL Server database wants to reference an Azure SQL database, it can do so using Linked Server
- When a fellow Azure SQL database wants to reference another Azure SQL database, only then it uses external data source

i.e. locally

```
-- Make a link to the cloud
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   
   @server=N'MyExternalServer', 
   @srvproduct=N'Azure SQL Db',
   @provider=N'SQLNCLI', 
   @datasrc=N'<server address>',
   @catalog='<database name>';
GO

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
    @rmtsrvname = '<server address>', 
    @useself = 'FALSE', 
    @locallogin=NULL,
    @rmtuser = '<username>',
    @rmtpassword = '<password>'
GO

select * from [MyExternalServer].[<database name>].[<schema>].[<table name>]
```

Whereas for Azure SQL:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<password>'; 
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ElasticDBQueryCred 
WITH IDENTITY = '<username>', 
SECRET = '<password>';  

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyElasticDBQueryDataSrc WITH 
    (TYPE = RDBMS, 
    LOCATION = '<server>', 
    DATABASE_NAME = '<database name>', 
    CREDENTIAL = ElasticDBQueryCred, 
) ; 


create schema <internalschema>

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE <internalschema>.<internaltablename>
(
    ... // list of columns
WITH 
( DATA_SOURCE = MyElasticDBQueryDataSrc,
SCHEMA_NAME = <schema>,
OBJECT_NAME = <table name>
) 

select * from <internalschema>.<internaltablename>
```

The challenge now is to make the database scripts be common using both approaches. To reference a table using Linked Server, it has to be addressed using four-part identifier `[server].[database].[schema].[tablename]`. Contrast this with external data source where it can be addressed just by using `[schema].[tablename]`.

Using inspiration from this question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74566/sql-server-using-4-part-identifiers-when-database-may-be-on-the-same-server, my approach is to create a synonym on my local database that redirects `[schema].[tablename]` to `[externalserver].[externaldatabase].[externalschema].[tablename]`.

i.e. locally:

```
create schema <internalschema>
CREATE SYNONYM <internalschema>.<internaltablename> FOR [MyExternalServer].[<database name>].[<schema>].[<table name>]
```

After which, the same statement would work for both cases:

```
select * from <internalschema>.<internaltablename>
```

EDIT:
One big problem with this approach is that you cannot use wrap your script under distributed transaction, because Azure SQL does not allow DTC.

Answer (score 0):

if we are talking about SQL Server, external data source/table/file format are supported starting from SQL Server 2016 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935022.aspx .

Comment: Unfortunately, SQL Server 2016 is still preview, and there is no Express edition for it at all

Comment: Yes... only customer preview.

Comment: I am reading this in 2018, and this is apparently still a problem with SQL Server 2017 because CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE with TYPE=RDMS still does not work to connect to Azure SQL from any on-premises SQL server edition I've tried.