# How to query/ Insert into - a Azure SQL Server from a local instance

Tags: sql-server, azure

What is the syntax for inserting / querying an Azure SQL Server database/table, from a local SQL instance?

I have Azure SQL server  - XXXXX.database.windows.net,1433
It contains a database  - MyTestDB
Table USERS

What is the syntax or how do I query the Azure DB, rom my local instance?

```
**SELECT * FROM [XXXX].[MYTESTDB].dbo.USERS**    ???
```

Error

**Reference to database/and or server name in 'XXXXX....' is not supported in this version of SQL Server**

Do I need an Azure Elastic Database ? If so how set it up?

thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried with Linked Server?

Comment: Yes.. could not get it to connect

Comment: First thing is to establish the link server and then it would be easy. You can access as you want right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried the linked server solution with my local SQL Express and it works fine. I created an AdventureWorks sample DB on Azure and I was able to query it from my local SQL Express like this:

Example:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   
   @server = N'MyExternalServer', 
   @srvproduct = N'Azure SQL Db',
   @provider = N'SQLNCLI', 
   @datasrc = N'adventureworks03.database.windows.net',
   @catalog = 'adventureworks';
GO

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
    @rmtsrvname = 'MyExternalServer', 
    @useself = 'FALSE', 
    @locallogin = NULL,
    @rmtuser = '{username}',
    @rmtpassword = '{password}'
GO

select * from [MyExternalServer].[adventureworks].[SalesLT].[Customer]
```

Here is the original post what I used:
[SQL Server Express equivalent for EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36735179/sql-server-express-equivalent-for-external-data-source)

Comment: Elastic Query only works between Azure SQL Databases?  I need my local/ on premise to Azure SQL

Comment: Yes, you are right, I updated my response, I just tried linked server solution, and it works fine, see the example above.